# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method send on channel sendSms) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sms

I doing custom app send sms auto for users

I used many lib but it not working and my code bellow

```
Future<void> sendSMS(phoneNumber, message) async {
const platform = MethodChannel('sendSms');
try {
  final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('send', <String, dynamic>{
   "phone": phoneNumber,
   "msg": message
 });
   print(result);
 } on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
 }
}
```

but when running my app throw exception with error:

```
 MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method send on channel sendSms)
```

Thanks for any suport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are creating a plugin yourself, it's unlikely you need to use the `invokeMethod` call directly. If you *use* a plugin (as I expect you are) then the plugin you use will provide you with regular Dart functions or classes that you can use to do what you want the plugin to do (for example, send an SMS).

For example, if you are using the [flutter_sms](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sms) plugin, then per that plugin's documentation you send an SMS using

```
String _result = await sendSMS(message: message, recipients: recipents)
        .catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    });
```

As you can see, you don't use `invokeMethodChannel`, because the plugin does that for you 'under the hood'.

Comment: I used flutter sms before but when sending a message it fills to the input of the message app default of the phone and it does not send my message